# postgresql join 2 tables and subquery with last value < date

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 3 tables: [bill_plans, biling_types, users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlucl.png)

### Sample data

**Bill_plans**

```
id, user_id, bill_plan_value, bill_type_id, bill_plan_date
1   1        100              7             2017-04-13
2   1        50               4             2017-03-13
3   1        70               7             2017-03-24
4   1        28               3             2017-02-21
```

**Billing_types**

```
id, bill_type,  parent_id
3   Платний             1
4   Безплатний          1
5   Адміністративний    2
6   Маркетинговий       2
7   Розвитку            2
2   Внутрішній білінг   0
1   Клієнтський білінг  0
```

**Users**

```
id, name
1, Адмін
2, Carl
3, Peter
```

### Need to get

```
id, user_id, bill_plan_value, bill_type_id, bill_plan_date, bill_type,  name
1   1        100              7             2017-04-13      Розвитку   Адмін
2   NULL     NULL             6             NULL            Маркетинговий   Адмін
3   NULL     NULL             5             NULL            Адміністративний   Адмін
4   NULL     NULL             4             NULL            Безплатний   Адмін
5   NULL     NULL             3             NULL            Платний      Адмін
```

And with other users same

### Tried to run

```
SELECT b.*, bt.*, u.name
FROM bill_plans as b
FULL JOIN billing_types as bt ON bt.id = b.bill_type_id
FULL JOIN users as u ON u.id = b.user_id
WHERE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.bill_plan_date) = $dateMonth OR
      b.bill_plan_date IS NULL AND bt.parent_id != 0 OR bt.parent_id IS NULL
```

Getting

```
[0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(7)
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["bill_plan_value"]=>
    string(3) "100"
    ["bill_type_id"]=>
    int(7)
    ["bill_plan_date"]=>
    string(10) "2017-04-13"
    ["bill_type"]=>
    string(16) "Tax"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "User1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(5)
    ["user_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["bill_plan_value"]=>
    NULL
    ["bill_type_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["bill_plan_date"]=>
    NULL
    ["bill_type"]=>
    string(33) "Administration"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

[0] is correct, but next results return NULL users. I need all users and all billings for users, even if bill_plan empty for user.

**Second step — getting last value**

Need to get last value from *bill_plans* where bill_plan_date < $date (closest)

Comment: Please update your question with sample data and expected output if possible.  Off the top of my head, you should be left joining users to billings, to bill plans, not the other way around, and _not_ using a full join.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks. Updated

Comment: I think that `need to get` is incorrect, because you stated that you don't want NULL users and yet there are NULLs in desired result, despite showing username in last column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CROSS JOIN**

```
SELECT b.*, bt.*, u.name
FROM bill_plans as b
RIGHT JOIN billing_types as bt ON bt.id = b.bill_type_id
CROSS JOIN users as u ON u.id = b.user_id
WHERE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.bill_plan_date) = $dateMonth 
      OR b.bill_plan_date IS NULL 
      AND bt.parent_id != 0 
      OR bt.parent_id IS NULL
```